# Design patterns for pre initialize data for one task

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

I have working on developing scheduling application as a start up and application take some time to complete. during the scheduling process I cannot use service calls to load data, because it will reduce the performance. It may cause to terminate the process if data access failed.

So I need to load required data before starting the scheduling process and discard that data after completing the schedule. This is some kind of caching but it doesn't need all the features in caching like check for expiries, discard expiries update new changes etc. Need to load once a month only for the scheduling.

So can somebody tell me what is the best design pattern to handle that situation. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps try here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ReutSharabani when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat thanks, I'll keep that in mind :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's a place for [Prototype](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-prototype) pattern, but you should also consider using some caching framework and just disable all fancy features like expiration, pinning, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the test automation patterns such

> need to load required data before starting the scheduling process and discard that data after completing the schedule.

is called fixtures. So what you need can be achieved with `setUp()` and `tearDown()` functionality. Generally a [Setup Decorator](http://xunitpatterns.com/Setup%20Decorator.html) will do just fine. It'll "bracket" the execution of the entire scheduling process with a set of matching setUp and tearDown "book ends".